# NextJS images - reload gif onClick

Tags: reactjs, next.js

so basically I'm using NextJS on my website and I have a problem. I have a button that onClick shows the gif that is looped forever. Whether I use Next/Image or simply img src with the public folder's source I cannot force mount the gif, so if the user clicks the animation and then close it, the animation will not start from the beginning, but from the last moment when it was closed.

I tried to use this function onClick, but I think that NextJS is still serving the pre-loaded file from the public folder. How to solve it? I want gif to start from the very beginning every time the user clicks on the reveal button.

```
const reloadGif = () => {
        setReload('/')
        setTimeout(() => {
            setReload('/InjectionGIF.gif')
        }, 5)
    }
```

Comment: PS I also tried the trick with the key props - still not working and in the network tab NEXT is still serving the same file without the reload

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the source itself. Something like this should work:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);

  const toggleReveal = () => {
    setHidden(!hidden);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper" onClick={toggleReveal}>
        <img
          src={
            hidden
              ? ''
              : 'https://media0.giphy.com/media/YTETMtpsueseikztWR/giphy.gif'
          }
          alt=""
          height="300"
          width="240"
        />
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .wrapper {
          background: #000;
          height: 300px;
          width: 240px;
        }
        img[src=''] {
          display: none;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

You can use `next/image` in place of `img`. Also, there may be many approaches to hide the image, like conditionally rendering the element, or replacing the source by 1x1 transparent image.

Here is a complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-fire-g36n1